# Github action is not triggered on Pull Request

Tags: github-actions

I have created the spring boot application. I have added a github action to build the project on pull request and push on `dev` branch. Following is the action

```
name: Backend Maven CI

on:
  push:
    branches: ["dev"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["dev"]

jobs:
  backend-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.repository_owner == 'mehtapuneet151'
    env:
      ...
      ...
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        ...
```

But the action Backend Maven CI is triggered only when code is pushed in dev branch NOT when pull request is created.

What changes are required to trigger action on pull request on dev branch?

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore - you're configured to run that workflow on pull requests _to_ `dev`, not from it to other branches.